# Steel radial belt showing on front tires only?

Tags: tires, steel

I have all new tires. Cannot figure out why but the front tires seem to being having some issue. I've had to replace the front more than the back. Today I was shocked when I inspected the front tires to see metal threadings/pins sticking out only on the inner edge of the tire, or closest to the engine. This was true for both the front tires. Could this be an alignment issue? shocks?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: this is probably an alignment issue.  Does you car drive in a straight line or does it want to turn to the left or right when driving down the road?

Comment: It does seem to turn slightly to the left

Answer (score 6):

I think it is definitely an alignment issue, and it is really dangerous to keep driving like that.

if the vehicle is a front wheel drive, it is obvious that the front tires wear out faster than the rear, but having wear on the inner side could be due to alignment and poor tire pressure could also be an issue but might not be in this case.

if they are new tires they should atleast last about 20k miles before the metal starts showing up.

have the alignment check done asap, in USA most shops do an alignment check for free or for about 10 bucks, do not use cheap Chinese tires(no offense if some one is using them).

one simple fix can be done by visually inspecting the alignment from the front and back side of the car, there are vidoes on youtube how to align your car wheels, but i recommend a professional, if you have no past experience in working on cars.

Comment: Some of your details are a little off.  When properly maintained, tires should last upwards of 40,000 miles (or more for good tires) unless you chose a very soft compound tire.  And you're not going to find anyone that will check an alignment for $10.  "Checking the alignment" is the same as "getting an alignment done", and you're looking at $80 and up for a front-end alignment.

Comment: http://www.monro.com/products-services/wheel-alignment, here is a link where you can get the car alignment for free. As you said th tires should last 40000 miles without a problem, the new michelins are rated for 80000 as well, I was just taking the worst guess on the tires that he had.

Comment: Ok, so I spoke too soon on the "no free alignment check".  I would advise against "free checks" like that because they're just trying to get you in the door to sell other services, but that's an entirely different topic.

Comment: @kasey That's not a couple for a free alignment, it's for a free alignment *check*.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling, yeah I meant the free alignment check not the free alignment, I think there was a typo in the comment, but the answer says free alignment check.

Comment: What about cheap Indonesian tires? lol I got a set for < $70 a piece and they're just as good as $100 hankooks seemingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alignment issue.  The camber is most likely off causing the tires to wear excessively on the inside edge.  Take the car in and have the alignment done.